# How can I make an image responsive when it is located in the CSS rather than the HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am editing a website template that has the homepage background image inserted in the CSS. The image is not responsive on mobile. The CSS points to a specific section and not the specific image. So I am guessing that is why it is not working. But I don't know how to point the responsive CSS to the image when it is in CSS and not HTML. How can I make the image responsive? Thanks!

```

```
#slider {
  background: url("../img/helloquence-61189.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 10% 0%;
  padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```

Comment: can you use bootstrap?

Comment: If you want to show full banner. Add background-size: contain in media query. or use Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#slider{
  background: url("../img/helloquence-61189.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use background-image:contain instead of cover

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    #slider {
  background: url("http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/150000/velka/banner-header-tapete-145002399028x.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 10% 0%;
  padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}  
  </style>
<div id=slider>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#slider {
  background: url("../img/helloquence-61189.jpg") no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% 100%; background-attachment: fixed; background-
  position: center center; position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This works! I can now see the full image on mobile view. But now on desktop view it is only showing the top part of the image.

Comment: Oh I just added the padding back in and that fixes the desktop view.

Comment: Bro if you want to shown desktop version then set side height using Jquery & after that you will perfect and use media query for responsive 

Var abc = $(window).height();

Set height on div then use 

$("#slider").css('height',abc+'px');

Comment: Please do not assume I am a Bro. Thanks.